# Abusing clustering columns, what disadvantages?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Suppose I have the 2 following tables with the same columns but different primary keys :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable1 ( 
       id UUID, 
       lastname text, 
       birthday timestamp, 
       nationality text
       PRIMARY KEY ((id))
);
```

VS

```
    CREATE TABLE myTable2 ( 
           id UUID, 
           lastname text, 
           birthday timestamp, 
           nationality text
           PRIMARY KEY ((id), lastname, birthday, nationality)
    );
```

As you see in this example, `myTable2` has 3 more clustering columns that `myTable1` (which has none).

Apart from the upserts, what are the other differences when reading or writing from `myTable1` VS `myTable2`? Is there a performance difference? How impactant it is?

For the record, I'm asking this because I read that columns of `COUNTER` type can be the only regular columns in a table. So I thought : *Why not set all the other columns as clustering columns?* (probably dumb but why?)

**edit:** To be more specific, I'm asking in the case where I won't be using the clustering columns for any sort of filtering in my queries. Will there be any significant performance difference between `myTable1` and `myTable2` when applying the two queries below?

```
INSERT INTO myTableX (id, lastname, birthday, nationality) VALUES (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000, 'Smith', '2013-03-10 00:00+0000', 'US');

SELECT * FROM myTableX WHERE id = 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case: the clustering columns will ensure all the records with the same id. This is very convenient if you will retrieve ranges of records, be stored together, and be kept in lexicographical order.

Following your example, the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (id, lastname, birthday, nationality) VALUES (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000, 'Smith', '2013-03-10 00:00+0000', 'US');
INSERT INTO myTable2 (id, lastname, birthday, nationality) VALUES (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000, 'Garcia', '2001-06-10 00:00+0000', 'ES');
INSERT INTO myTable2 (id, lastname, birthday, nationality) VALUES (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000, 'Smith', '1978-09-10 00:00+0000', 'UK');
```

will be recorded in the database as:

```
id                                   | lastname | birthday              | nationality
-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-------------
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | Garcia   | 2001-06-10 00:00+0000 | ES
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | Smith    | 1978-09-10 00:00+0000 | UK
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | Smith    | 2013-03-10 00:00+0000 | US
```

This table structure will be ideal if your use case requires to retrieve or filter entries identified with a specific `id` and filter them by

- lastname
- lastname and birthday
- lastname, birthday, and nationality.

If your use case requires to *get all the records from this id that are from US*  or *get the users with this id whose birthday is today*, the engine will need to execute a full scan of the partition, affecting the query's performance.

In Cassandra, the definition of the tables should always depend on how the data will be used.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really answer my question. I've edited it to be even more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a question of advantages vs disadvantages of using clustering columns. It also isn't a question of performance.

The use of clustering columns determines the way data is physically stored on disk and how it is structured in the table.

When you only have a partition key in the primary key (as in your `myTable1`, **each partition in the table will ONLY ever have one row.**

For tables with a compound primary key (i.e. partition key + clustering column(s) as in your `myTable2`), **each partition in the table will have ONE OR MORE rows**.

In your `myTable1`, each `id` can only ever have one last name. In plain terms, you can store one person's information in each partition (record). This is the traditional two-dimensional table like in a spreadsheet.

In `myTable2`, each `id` can have one or more rows of last names. This means that you can store several people's information in each partition -- one record has multiple rows associated with it. This is a multi-dimensional table and a big reason why NoSQL is more powerful for modelling real-world data than relational databases. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. For the sake of the example, say that `myTable2` partition's key would already be a primary key on its own, meaning that one partition will always only have 1 row (this will be enforced by the client application). In this case, you say that setting all the "rest" of the columns as clustering columns will add no significant overhead to the queries? So if I need to add a `COUNTER` column to my table, I can just set all the rest of the "normal columns" as "clustering columns"?

Comment: Your first sentence isn't true in the strict sense because your second table has a compound primary key. And I think you're confusing it with counter tables which is a completely separate discussion. Those are two different things. :)